# Hadoop job dependency clashes with older one from distributive

Tags: java, hadoop, classpath

I'm using hadoop-2.5.2 linux distributive to run a job with custom Shuffle plugin.
Mapper and Reducer implementations are packed together with other dependencies into single.jar

Run with command:

```
bin/hadoop -jar simple.jar
```

The problem is that Mapper implementation depends on hamcrest 1.3, but Hadoop distribution is supplied with mockito-all, which contains older matchers (from hamcrest 1.1).
Thus, during job run I've got:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError(org.hamcrest.core.AnyOf.anyOf(Lorg/hamcrest/Matcher;Lorg/hamcrest/Matcher;)Lorg/hamcrest/core/AnyOf;)
out of org.hamcrest.Matchers#anyOf[133]
```

So, the AnyOf.class was loaded from
"hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar"

Obviously, I need to say Hadoop to load user libraries first.
I tried 2 approaches:

1) Set "mapreduce.job.classloader" to "true"

2) Set "mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first" to "true"
both and separately.

With no luck.

Any hint would be really appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the distributed cache. The hadoop framework will copy the third part jars to local disk in all task tracker nodes.

"The jar will be placed in distributed cache and will be made available to all of the job’s task attempts."
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/

So you can use, for example:

```
hadoop jar my-example.jar -libjars mockito-correct-version.jar
```

You could also include the mockito jar inside your hadoop jar, and create a super jar with all dependencies.